# Kendo mvc sort doesnt working

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I used code in Kendo to sort by date:

```
.Sort(sort => sort.Add("CreationDateUtc").Ascending())
```

And this grid is not even rendering, I got an error:

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Next I tried to use Sortable(), it's rendering but when I click on column name I got the same problem. Does someone know what's happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Probably a datasource issue. Show your grid code for starters. Column definitions, etc.